# How to fix android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException error?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have tested the application on my device and few emulators. The app doesn't crash and I don't see anything on the LogCat but I can see around 400 crashes within 22 hours in ANRs & crashes.

The error doesn't say which resource is missing to check it and if it's missing why it is not crashing on my phone?

This is the line which causes the crash:

```
int themeLayout = sharedPreferences.getInt(THEME_KEY, R.layout.input_1);
mInputView = (LatinKeyboardView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                themeLayout, null);
```

If shared preference returns null then I assigned a default value to use that one but still, it crash. I checked the layout and it exists, also check the content.

I created the emulator with the same specification but it doesn't crash.

> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException:    at
>   android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue (ResourcesImpl.java:202)
>   at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser
>   (Resources.java:2968)   at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout
>   (Resources.java:1984)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate
>   (LayoutInflater.java:425)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate
>   (LayoutInflater.java:378)   at
>   com.sunzala.afghankeyboard.android.SoftKeyboard.onCreateInputView
>   (SoftKeyboard.java:163)   at
>   com.sunzala.afghankeyboard.android.SoftKeyboard.onStartInput
>   (SoftKeyboard.java:242)   at
>   android.inputmethodservice.InputMethodService.doStartInput
>   (InputMethodService.java:2641)   at
>   android.inputmethodservice.InputMethodService$InputMethodImpl.startInput
>   (InputMethodService.java:590)   at
>   android.inputmethodservice.IInputMethodWrapper.executeMessage
>   (IInputMethodWrapper.java:186)   at
>   com.android.internal.os.HandlerCaller$MyHandler.handleMessage
>   (HandlerCaller.java:37)

**Edit:**
I found this error:

> E/dalvikvm: Could not find class
>   'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering

Comment: I would expect your code to crash for some updates to your app for where the preference is set. Resource IDs can change on every build. They are *not* safe to persist, as you are doing. Whether that is the cause of this specific crash, I cannot say, but you need to rework this code to use some value that *you* control as the preference value, not a resource ID.

Comment: @CommonsWare I am storing value with this line `editor.putInt(THEME_KEY, R.layout.input_8).apply();` when app runs first time. The value is not stored statically. Do you think it still matters? Thanks

Comment: The actual `int` value that you reference as `R.layout.input_8` can vary from build to build. The value that you save in the `SharedPreferences` today may be invalid in a week, after the user has upgraded to a newer version of your app. Do not persist `R` values, as they are not constant between builds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `R` values that we refer to in Java code, such as `R.layout.input_8`, are `public static final int` values on a code-generated `R` class. You will find that class in the `build/generated/source/r/` directory of your module. The file will be fairly large, but you will see stuff like:

```
  public static final class layout {
    public static final int activity_main=0x7f050000;
  }
```

That number (`0x7f050000`) is generated by the build tools (`aapt`, specifically, IIRC). And *that value can change from build to build*. As a result, it is not safe to persist such a number. Otherwise, you wind up with scenarios like this:

- User installs your app
- User does something in your app that causes you to persist a value (e.g., `editor.putInt(THEME_KEY, R.layout.input_8).apply();`)
- Time passes
- You ship an update to your app, where, as it turns out, the number for `R.layout.input_8` changes
- The user installs the update to your app
- Your code calls `sharedPreferences.getInt(THEME_KEY, R.layout.input_1);` and retrieves a number that *used* to be a resource ID... but now is just a number, or points to some different resource
- Your code crashes
- The user gets frustrated and throws their phone against a wall

<sub>Note: no actual phones or walls were harmed in the creation of this scenario</sub>

This is *a* problem with your code. I do not know if it is *the* problem that is triggering your crashes, but it could be.

The problem is that you are persisting a value (`0x7f050000`) that you do not control. You think that `R.layout.input_8` will always be `0x7f050000`, but that is not the case.

What you need to do is store something else in the preference, then use that to look up the proper ID. There are two main approaches for this.

One is to use a simple index. Your naming scheme suggests that you have a series of numbered layouts, at least through `8`. So, you could save a number between `1` and `8` in the `SharedPreferences`, then use that as an index into an array:

```
static final int[] THE_LAYOUTS={R.layout.input_1, R.layout.input_2, R.layout.input_3, R.layout.input_4, R.layout.input_5, R.layout.input_6, R.layout.input_7, R.layout.input_8};
```

In this solution, `editor.putInt(THEME_KEY, R.layout.input_8).apply();` turns into `editor.putInt(THEME_KEY, 8).apply();`, and `sharedPreferences.getInt(THEME_KEY, R.layout.input_1);` turns into `THE_LAYOUTS[sharedPreferences.getInt(THEME_KEY, 1)];`.

The other is to save the *string* `"R.layout.input_8"`. Given that, and `getIdentifier()` on a `Resources` object, you can get back the `int` value associated with that string for your current build. Personally, I find this to be more awkward and slower, but it's an option.

Comment: I'm facing an issue where i've implemented dynamic module, whenever i run the application from android studio its working fine. But after i've uploaded it to playstore for internal testing, i download the on demand module. It gets installed but it crashes after that saying resource not found. Any idea how to resolve it?

Comment: @AagamShah: I have never used dynamic modules, sorry.